# DFS Replication, Users HOME folder - seems not to catch all files... any hints?

Tags: dfs-r

I amm moving stuff out of a file Server. I am using DFS for that - the Folders are anyway in a DFS tree, so I can set up a replication temporarily, then drop the old Folder. Works nice, EXCEPT for the Folder containing the users home drives. Which, incidentally, is also the one I can not see all files in due to my permissions.

Small Setup. We have 159mb in the users directories, 1280 files, 133 Folders original.

The copy only has 157mb, 1269 files, 133 Folders.

Anyone knwos of a way to find out what files are missing? IS this a Problem (could be some Caching files that are regenerated). Users are all offline (weekend) ;) This is pretty much the last share - all others had exactly ZERO issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DFS by default skips .tmp and .bak files, plus any files that start with ~. You can edit this list of filters in the DFS Management MMC under Replicated Folders. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753409.aspx for details.

Comment: is there a log of skipped files somewhere? or at least somehing like "14 .tmp files" etc. - so I can check whether it is only those?

Comment: i think by default, the log does not record these skips. you have to crank up the logging level. however, it's probably easier to just do `dir /s /b *.bak` and `dir /s /b *.tmp` and `dir /s /b ~*` under both replicas and compare the results.

Comment: The Problem is that I dont ahve read acess to all home directories as per security requirements ;)

Answer (score 4):

Did you make sure none of the issues mentioned in [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2010/11/01/common-dfsr-configuration-mistakes-and-oversights.aspx) apply to your situation? Did you create a [diagnostic report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778105.aspx)? What does it say? Also check the backlog:

```
dfsrdiag backlog /rgname:GROUP /rfname:FOLDER /smem:SOURCE /rmem:DESTINATION /v
```

Aside from that I'd recommend to fix permissions on the home directories. Best practice is to give full access to SYSTEM, Administrators and the particular user. The parent folder should have the following permissions:

- `SYSTEM`: full access
- `Administrators`: full access
- `Authenticated Users`: create folders (this folder only)
- `CREATOR OWNER`: full access (subfolders and files only)